# Firebase - can't use setValue() on LHS of assignment?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using Android Studio 1.5, and using the following code straight from the documentation itself

```
  public class User {
        private int birthYear;
        private String fullName;

        public User() {
        }

        public User(String fullName, int birthYear) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.birthYear = birthYear;
        }

        public long getBirthYear() {
            return birthYear;
        }

        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }
    }
```

Firebase code

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/android/saving-data/fireblog");
Firebase alanRef = ref.child("users").child("alanisawesome");
User alan = new User("Alan Turing", 1912);
alanRef.setValue(alan);
```

It throws an error `cannot resolve symbol setValue`. When I try the autocomplete feature, there's no suggestion for `setValue();` however if used on the RHS of the assignment operation like in the code below, it works. Can someone help me out here?

```
 Firebase abc = ref.setValue(); //seems to work
```

Comment: It compiles without problems for me (Android Studio 1.5 preview 2): https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebasedemo/stackoverflow/Activity33955548.java. The actual `setValue()` operation of course fails, since I don't have permission to write to the `docs-examples` Firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen your entire code but I am assuming that you tried using setValue outside a method. The setValue method can only be invoked inside a method.